# calling colnames() insides user define function

Tags: r, function

I want to define a function AUC as follows...!

```
AUC<-function(model, df, label_name) {
  
pred = data.frame(predict(model, df, type = 'prob')) 
colnames(pred) = paste(colnames(pred), label_name)  

}
```

And when it is called as follows

```
abc<-AUC(rf_res,df=test_df,label_name="_pred_RF")
head(abc)
```

The function is returning

```
[1] "setosa _pred_RF"     "versicolor _pred_RF" "virginica _pred_RF"
```

but what I require is that it should return (like for iris data set) as follows

```
 setosa _pred_RF versicolor _pred_RF virginica _pred_RF
6             1.00                0.00                  0
7             1.00                0.00                  0
17            1.00                0.00                  0
18            1.00                0.00                  0
19            0.98                0.02                  0
22            1.00                0.00                  0
```

Out side the function same lines

```
pred = data.frame(predict(rf_res, test_df, type = 'prob')) 
colnames(pred) = paste(colnames(pred), "_pred_RF")  

head(pred)

setosa _pred_RF versicolor _pred_RF virginica _pred_RF
6             1.00                0.00                  0
7             1.00                0.00                  0
17            1.00                0.00                  0
18            1.00                0.00                  0
19            0.98                0.02                  0
22            1.00                0.00                  0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please edit your post to include the datasets or change your code to use a dataset that ships with R.  The following code will generate a code snippet with 10 random records that you can paste into your original post: dput(dplyr::sample_n(YourDatasetsNameGoesHere, 10)). To use my code, you may need to install dplyr with: install.packages("dplyr")

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is simply that you aren't returning the data frame from the function. Here's a full working example of your function in action:

```r
library(randomForest)

AUC<-function(model, df, label_name) 
{
  pred <- data.frame(predict(model, df, type = 'prob')) 
  colnames(pred) <- paste(colnames(pred), label_name)
  return(pred)
}

rf_res <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris)

abc <- AUC(rf_res, df = iris, label_name = "_pred_RF")
head(abc)
#>   setosa _pred_RF versicolor _pred_RF virginica _pred_RF
#> 1               1                   0                  0
#> 2               1                   0                  0
#> 3               1                   0                  0
#> 4               1                   0                  0
#> 5               1                   0                  0
#> 6               1                   0                  0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Dear Allan Cameron, Thanks a lot for your support now it's working :)